# Unity Physics collision metrix doesn't work on ParticleCollisions

Tags: unity, c#

I have this Physics collision metrix(1).
I have *Player* layer on the ship and *PlayerShells* on Particles whitch's my shooting.

The problem:
When I shoot, `OnParticleCollision` on my *shells* collides with *player*, but as you can see on the picture it shouldn't happen.

Proofing my theory, I testet it: (2) and (3) screenshoots;

My "collision" code:

```
private void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
        {
            SetDamage(other.GetComponent<ISetDamage>());
            
            //Creating hit effect
            _mainParticles.GetCollisionEvents(other, _collEvent);
            Vector3 pos = _collEvent[0].intersection;   //hit posotion
            Quaternion newRot =
               Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, -transform.rotation.y, transform.rotation.z);
               //Tryed to rotate effect like opposite from bullet, but it doesn't work for now

            switch (other.GetComponent<Stats>().GetMatter)
            {
                case Matter.Steel:
                    Instantiate(_hitSteel, pos, newRot);
                    break;
                case Matter.Wood:
                    Instantiate(_hitWood, pos, newRot);
                    break;
                case Matter.Flesh:
                    Instantiate(_hitFlesh, pos, newRot);
                    break;
                case Matter.Dirt:
                    Instantiate(_hitDirt, pos, newRot);
                    break;
                case Matter.Stone:
                    Instantiate(_hitStone, pos, newRot);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

[image: Physics collision metrix]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?? :(

Comment: Which of these objects has your particle system on it? That doesn't appear to be shown in the screenshots.

Comment: no, it doesn't shown here. It's just screenshots that collisiom metrix works for simple objects. I'll add particles screenshoot

Comment: If you expand the Collision module on your Particle System, do you see a "Collides With" parameter?

Comment: oh god yes! Didn't see that before! Thank you!

Comment: Want to post your solution as an answer if it's working for you? (I should also note, I've never used this feature before. I found that by searching "unity particle collision" and just clicking the top few links - so don't underestimate your ability to find this info!)

Comment: ahah, you it's one of the things like if u want to hode something, hide it in the most visible place :D And yes, post that as an answer, it worked for me :)

Comment: I was asking if you wanted to post your own answer, since you're able to take screenshots/code snippets of your working configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer :D Simple as a pie. Thank you again, my friend @DMGregory
[image]